# Cannot embed my password during first login with Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I'm trying to log into Kali Linux for the first time via my UTM VM. After I embed my Phrase, the terminal is asking my login and password. The login Works just fine, however, I can't embed a password, I type one but it doesn't populate and then times out after 60 seconds.

Comment: My Kali system does not embed login or password. Kali 2018 to now Kali 2022 - normal. Ubuntu and Windows do not embed passwords.. Security.

Comment: Please provide the type of username and password you are entering.  Not the same one, but similar characters

Comment: Do you perhaps mean the characters of the password you are typing do not show in the login field visibly? Or no typing seems to work in the password field? A better word for this may be "enter" rather than "embed, which means to store inside, more or less, and isn't really what you do with a password in a login field.